# How to display banner images which look good on both desktop and mobile view

Tags: reactjs, mobile, progressive-web-apps, desktop, banner

I have a progressive web app developed in reactjs and in this
I am using banner images which look good on mobile view, but when I switch to laptop view the banner images look big.

I tried to set the height property, but the image looks squeezed on laptop view.
The CSS code for the same is pasted below

```
banner-container {
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 45px;

    .banner-img {
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }

 }

@media (min-width: 767px) {
 .banner-container {
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 200px !important;
    max-width: 100%;

    .banner-img {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      max-height: 300px;
    }

  }
}
```

What is the best way to display banner images which look good on both laptop and mobile view

Comment: What do you mean by look good? Do you want to change the aspect ratio?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily manage your banner image with this css property:

```
object-fit: contain
```

Or you can look into different values of object-fit in this doc:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Comment: Hi Noman, Thanks for the response. But the object-fit: contain makes banner image small in laptop view. It does not scale end to end. We want the banner image width to be 100% in both mobile and laptop view.

Comment: you can play with its different properties like cover, fill, etc.